# How to render a rails template in cusotmer.io message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I am customizing devise confirmation mail and sending through customer.io. In customer.io I need to set the confirmation.html.erb in message page.

```
customerio = Customerio::Client.new(customerio["site_id"], customerio["api_key"],:json => false)
customerio.track(2,
  "samplemailer",
  sender_name: "rubyonrailsdeveloper.com",
  sender_email: "sample@sample.com",
  subject: "asfadsfsd",
  to: "sample1@yopmail.com",
  body: message)
```